# Android - Is it possible to enable Firebase Crashlytics for "debug" build variant

Tags: android, firebase, crash, crashlytics

Firebase only seems to log crashes happening on "Release" build variant. How could I also enable it on "debug"?

Answer (score 1):

It should work by default, however you can try manually making sure reports are being sent by adding this to your AndroidManifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="${crashlyticsCollectionEnabled}" />
```

and then this block into your app level build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [crashlyticsCollectionEnabled:"true"]
            ...
        }
```